# how to update or assign 2d array using useState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, 2d

```
const [updatedList, setUpdatedList] = useState([[1,2],[1,2]]);
    try {
        const resData = await axios.post("/getlist");
        if (resData.status === 200) {
            setUpdatedList(resData.data.list);  
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("ndsjkncjksnc");
    }
    console.log(updatedList);
```

here resData.data.list is in the form [[122,4,3,2],[5,4,3,32],[54,5,6,7,77],[2,3,5,7,5,4]]
in console.log(updatedList), I am still getting [[1,2].[1.2]]
The array is not updating to [[122,4,3,2],[5,4,3,32],[54,5,6,7,77],[2,3,5,7,5,4]]
Any help would be highly appreciated.

I tried using setUpdatedList(updatedList=>[...updatedList,resData.data.list]), It isnt working too.
****the try block is executing i.e resData.status=200

Comment: What is your try/catch for ? You should try with .then(() => ...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesnt seem to be a problem here

Comment: Did you try like this ?
const [updatedList, setUpdatedList] = useState([[1,2],[1,2]]);

const resData = await axios.post("/getlist")
    .then((response) => {
        setUpdatedList(response.data.list);
        console.log(updatedList);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });


resData();

Comment: Please do format your code

Comment: Yes I tried but the updatedList is not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an useEffect with your updatedList as a dependency. This will print your updatedList, as soon as it has changed.
If you put your console.log after the try catch, your component will just render, start the axios request and skip directly to the console.log (which will log the initial state [1,2],[1,2]).

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(updatedList);
}, [updatedList]);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried but updatedList is not getting updated